# Using Shiny Reactive

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

Problem: I need to set two flags; 'valid' flag and 'test' flag, if the respective action button is clicked.
For example, if one clicks on 'test' button then test flag will be True and valid flag will be False. second time, I again click 'valid' button, then valid flag should be True and test flag should be False. No matter how many time one clicks each button, the flag for which the button is being clicked presently will be True and the second one will be False. So, at any point of time, both flags should not be True at once.

I am not able to achieve this. For first click on each button, the result is as expected but after the second time clicking of the same button afterward, not getting desired results.

```
if (interactive()) {
  shinyApp(
    ui = basicPage(
      actionBttn("valid", "Validate:"),
      actionBttn("test", 'Test')
    ),
    server = function(input, output, session) {
      observeEvent(c(input$valid, input$test), {
        valid <- ifelse(input$valid > 0, T, F) #validation.flag() 
        test <- ifelse(input$test > 0, T, F)  #prediction.flag()
        print(valid)
        print(test)
        print("")
        # do something based on valid and test flag
      })
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of an action button is the **count** of how many times it has been clicked, so you would have to store it to determine if it has been clicked one more time.

The easiest solution here is to have **2** `observeEvents`, one for each button, and call a function with the clicked button as a parameter :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

shinyApp(

    ui = basicPage(
        actionBttn("valid", "Validate"),
        actionBttn("test", 'Test')
    ),

    server = function(input, output, session) {
        my_function <- function(is_test) {
            if (is_test)
                print("Test clicked")
            else
                print("Validate clicked")
        }
        
        observeEvent(input$test, my_function(TRUE))
        observeEvent(input$valid, my_function(FALSE))
    }
)
```